# hiveQL counter limit exceeded error

Tags: hiveql

I am running a create table query in Hiveql and obtain the following error when it is run:

**Status: Failed
Counters limit exceeded: Too many counters: 2001 max=2000
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Counters limit exceeded: Too many counters: 2001 max=2000**

I have attempted to set the counters to to a greater number, i.e. 
set tez.counters.max=16000;

However, it still falls over with the same error.

My query incorporates 13 left joins but the data sets are relatively small (1,000's rows).  The query did work when there were roughly 10 joins but since I've added additional joins it has started to fail.

Any suggestions on how I can configure this to work would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: May be you should check the value of property `mapreduce.job.counters.limit` in your _mapred-site.xml_

Answer (score 0):

You need to find real initial error log from failed container. The error you have shown here is not initial error. 2001 containers (including their restart attempts) have failed because of some other error (which you really need to fix),  then all job was terminated, all other containers were killed because of Failed Counters limit.  Go to Job tracker and find some failed (not killed) container and read it's log. The real problem is not in limit and changing the Failed Counters limit will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Divide your query into multiple step and then run it.

As you said your query works with 10 joins,So first create the table which has data with first 10 joins and then with the new table,create other table which has data from first table and three other tables.

I faced the same issue as I was applying union all statement on 100 tables.But when I started to run only 10 tables at a time it works.

Hope This Helps!!!!